# Function to print all combinations of 2 letters length Using the English alphabet A-Z and digits 0-9?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I want a function in JavaScript to print all  to print all combinations of 2 letters length Using the English alphabet A-Z and digits 0-9, the generated combination shouldn't start with a number.

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested approach by using a combination pattern.

```js
var temp = Array.from({ length: 36 }, (_, i) => i.toString(36).toUpperCase()),
    result = [temp.slice(10), temp]
        .reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => v + w)), []));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Is this sarcasm? It looks as if you deliberately posted the densest possible answer without any explanation because the question is very basic and shows no effort.

Comment: @m69, hm, after your question ... it looks so.

Answer (score 1):

Results in an array of strings, which do not start with digits:

```js
const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('');
const digits = "0123456789".split('');
const alphabet = letters.concat(digits);

const result = [].concat.apply([], letters.map(a => alphabet.map(b => a + b)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over all letters:

```
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var nums = "0123456789";

var result = [];

for(var letter of letters){
 for(var letter2 of letters){
  result.push( letter + letter2);
 }
 for(var num of nums){
  result.push(letter + num);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
for (var i = 26; i--;) {
    for (var j = 10; j--;) console.log(letters[i]+j);
    for (var j = 26; j--;) console.log(letters[i]+letters[j]);
}
```

Comment: You asked *print all combinations*, this code can of course be altered for a different scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```js
letters = "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA";
for (var i = 26; i--;) {    
    for (var j = 26; j--;) console.log(letters[i]+letters[j]);
}
```